# Another case where whitespace matters (maybe?)

Tags: c++, syntax, c++11, whitespace, template-aliases

Is this another case, where whitespace matters in C++, or is it a compiler bug? Is the following code syntactically correct?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool cond>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if<cond, int>::type;

template <int n, EnableIf<n == 1>=0>
void func()
{}
```

Intel C++ Composer fails to compile it saying: "invalid combination of type specifiers". But add single whitespace in the signature and it compiles just fine:

```
template <int n, EnableIf<n == 1> =0>
void func()
{}
```

Comment: Well, it's not supposed to be `<n == (1>=0)>`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a case where whitespace matters. The compiler will match the biggest symbol it can, so it matches `>=`. The whitespace causes it to parse as you intended.